# open popup window with rails link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I was trying to open a popup window using rails link_to. But unfortunately, I am running into some problems. When I go to the new page, no popup window is displayed.

I used rails 2.3.2

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "new payment", new_project_voucher_voucher_payment_path(@project, @voucher ), "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#new_voucher_payment" %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<div id ="new_voucher_payment" class="modal fade"  role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
        <p>hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**How can I make the popup appear?**

Comment: try put '#' as the link instead of `new_project_voucher_voucher_payment_path`. You're linking to a new page instead of a modal.

Comment: thanks.but this is not working.

Comment: Just in case, have you double checked Bootstrap's JavaScript is loaded in your page? Tried in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvxLcvvy/) it works for me.

Comment: you put above codes in same page.it is also works for me. but i want above codes are in different view pages.how to handle different page path and div id?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to popup a modal with voucher payments new controller better approach is to respond new as js

> app/views/project_vouchers/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "new payment", new_project_voucher_voucher_payment_path(@project, @voucher ) remote: true do %>
....
<div class="modal fade" id="new_voucher_payment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

> app/views/project_vouchers/voucher_payments.js.erb

```
$("#new_voucher_payment").html("<%=j render 'voucher_payment', object: @voucher_payments %>");
$('#new_voucher_payment').modal('show');
```

> app/views/project_vouchers/_voucher_payment_form.html.erb

```
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
      <p>hello!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
      # your code comes here  
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

> app/controllers/voucher_payments_controller.rb

```
class VoucherPaymentsController < ApplicationController
  ....
  def new
    ....
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {
        # write the code for html response
      }
      format.js {
       @voucher_payments
      }
    end
  end
  ....
end
```